# Line missing from species accumulation curve

Tags: r

I found a code (below), adapted it to a basic set of my data and it worked!

Link to Ants.csv [here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b5d1bbf2dd81d75ffab0561bd8423eb5/Ants.csv)

```r
library(readxl)
library(vegan)

data<- read_excel("C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/Raw_data/Code_source/Ants.xlsx")

ants<-data[2:16]

Curve = specaccum(ants, method = "random",permutations = 999)

plot(Curve,ci=0,ci.type=c("line"),col="red",ylab="Number of Species",main="Calitzdorp")
axis(1, at=1:10)
```

However, when I use any other data the plot window opens a sheet with x and y axes, but no line?
Can anyone perhaps tell me why I'm missing a line now suddenly? Below is a copy of my code that works except for the line is missing:

Link to Ant_data_R [here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/6ad1cdc44cef2584711616e6fec4128f/Ant_data_R.csv)

```r
library(readxl)
library(vegan)

data<-read_excel("C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/Raw_data/Code_source/Ant_data_R.xlsx",sheet = "CA")

ants<-data[2:16]

Curve = specaccum(ants, method = "random",permutations = 999)

plot(Curve,ci=0,ci.type=c("line"),col="red",ylab="Number of Species",main="Calitzdorp",ylim=c(0,20))

axis(1, at=1:20)
```

When I view the dataframe everything looks fine, so I don't think it's because of the different excel sheets.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of your dataframe `Ants.xlsx` and `Ant_data_R.xlsx` ? Check this link to know how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: could it be that specifying `ylim=c(0,20)` in `plot` is causing the problem? Try removing the `ylim` argument and see if that helps. Otherwise, yes we'd need to see what your data look like to help more

Comment: @dc37 Links to the CSV have been linked in the text.

Comment: @AndyRominger have tried removing the ylim argument, but still, no line appears on the graph. Also, the data have been linked in the text. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get several issues in your code. Basically, your error is to try to apply straight a code to any dataframe without checking that the dataframe as the same structure as the one used in the example.

Let me explain, here you see the output of the `head` of both your data you provided as `csv` that I import using this code:

```r
data <- read.table("../Ants.csv", sep = ";", header = T)
data2 <- read.table("../Ant_data_R.csv", sep = ";", header = T)
```

For `Ants`:

```r
> head(data[1:6])
          No Sp.1 Sp.2 Sp.3 Sp.4 Sp.5
1 Transect 1    0    0    0    0    0
2 Transect 2    0    0    0    0    0
3 Transect 3    0    4    0    0    2
4 Transect 4    0    0    0    0    0
5 Transect 5    0    1    0    0    1
6 Transect 6    0    1    0    0    0
```

For `Ant_data_R`:

```r
> head(data2[1:6])
  Site Habitat No Sp.1 Sp.2 Sp.3
1   CA       H  1   NA   NA   NA
2   CA       H  2   NA   NA   NA
3   CA       H  3   NA   NA   NA
4   CA       H  4   NA   NA   NA
5   CA       H  5   NA   NA   NA
6   CA       H  6   NA   NA   NA
```

As you can see, 1) there is more descriptive columns in the first columns of the second file. 2) In the second file, missing values are filled with `NA` instead of `0`.

So, in your code you can't use straight `ants <- data[2:16]` as provided by the example because you will have different output:

Here for the first dataframe:

```r
ants <- data[2:16]

> head(ants[1:6])
  Sp.1 Sp.2 Sp.3 Sp.4 Sp.5 Sp.6
1    0    0    0    0    0   15
2    0    0    0    0    0    3
3    0    4    0    0    2   13
4    0    0    0    0    0   15
5    0    1    0    0    1    6
6    0    1    0    0    0    9
```

And here for the second one:

```r
ants2 <- data2[2:16]

> head(ants2[1:6])
  Habitat No Sp.1 Sp.2 Sp.3 Sp.4
1       H  1   NA   NA   NA   NA
2       H  2   NA   NA   NA   NA
3       H  3   NA   NA   NA   NA
4       H  4   NA   NA   NA   NA
5       H  5   NA   NA   NA   NA
6       H  6   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

As you can see the output is very different. In the first dataframe, it will select numerical values compatibles with the `specaccum` function but in the second case you will have character values and NA.

So, the solution is to filter and select only columns of interest. We can do that using `dplyr` (other ways exists):

```r
library(vegan)
library(tidyverse)
ants2 <- data2 %>% filter(., Site == "CA") %>% select(., contains("Sp.")) %>% replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Now the output of `ants2` look like:

```r
> head(ants2[1:6])
  Sp.1 Sp.2 Sp.3 Sp.4 Sp.5 Sp.6
1    0    0    0    0    0    0
2    0    0    0    0    0    0
3    0    0    0    0    0    0
4    0    0    0    0    0    0
5    0    0    0    0    0    0
6    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

And if you are applying the `specaccum` function and you are plotting them, you get:

```r
Curve = specaccum(ants, method = "random",permutations = 999)
Curve2 = specaccum(ants2, method = "random",permutations = 999)

plot(Curve,ci=0,ci.type=c("line"),col="red",ylab="Number of Species",main="Calitzdorp", ylim = c(2,15))
axis(1, at=1:10)
lines(Curve2,ci=0,ci.type=c("line"),col="blue")
legend("topleft", legend = c("Ants", "Ants_data_R"), col = c("red","blue"), bty = F, lty = 1)
```

[image]

Hope it helps you to figure out your error in the processing of the second dataframe.
Let me know if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was as easy as filling all my N/A cells with a "0" and my curves are working beautifully now!